# Suspend/Pause process when out of space?

Tags: linux, bash

I was wondering if it is possible to suspend/pause a process in Bash when the disk is running out of space. For example if the free disk space on the server I am working falls below 100 Gb to pause it instead of having it crash when 0 available disk space is reached.

I couldn't find any question similar to mine, but if there is kindly link it. I am very new to Informatics as I have recently started a thesis in Genomics, so I am not even sure if this is possible.

Cheers

David

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not - you can "pause" any process in linux. In pseudocode, even with some state variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash some_bash_process &
pid=$!
trap 'kill "$pid"' EXIT

paused=false
while process_still_running "$pid"; do
   if free_disc_space_below 100G; then
       if ! "$paused"; then
          paused=true
          kill -s SIGSTOP "$pid"
       fi
   else
       if "$paused"; then
          paused=false
          kill -s SIGCONT "$pid"
       fi
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

Research running process in the background in shell, signals and `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` signals and their behavior for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df` to check the disk usage periodically. If you find that there is not enough space, pause the process by sending a signal.

```
processThatMightRunOutOfDiskSpace &
pid=$!
while
  [ -d "/proc/$pid" ] &&
  [ "$(df --output=avail / | tail -n1)" -gt 1048576 ]
do
  sleep 5
done
kill -TSTP "$pid"
```

Make sure that you specify the correct file system for `df`. Here I used `/`. But when your process writes data to another file system (for instance a separate file system mounted on `/home`) then you have to specify that instead.

`df` reports the free space in 1KB-Blocks. `1048576` is 1024*1024, the number of 1KB-blocks needed to fill one 1GB.

Here we used the the signal SIGTSTP because I assumed that your process is a bash script. SIGSTP is the signal `bash` sends to a foreground process when you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>. However, this signal can be ignored. If it doesn't work, use SIGSTOP (`kill -STOP`) instead.
In both cases, to continue the stopped process use `kill -CONT "$pid"`.